# No route matches [PATCH] "/self-care2/commonController" when update data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 4.2 with Ruby 2.1.5

Here is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "services#index"  
  resources :apis, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :commons, path: "/self-care2/commonController" do
      collection do
          post :search, to: "commons#search"
      end
  end
end
```

Here is my rake routes result:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                     Controller#Action
       root GET    /                                               services#index
       apis POST   /apis(.:format)                                 apis#create
    new_api GET    /apis/new(.:format)                             apis#new
search_commons POST   /self-care2/commonController/search(.:format)   commons#search
    commons GET    /self-care2/commonController(.:format)          commons#index
            POST   /self-care2/commonController(.:format)          commons#create
 new_common GET    /self-care2/commonController/new(.:format)      commons#new
edit_common GET    /self-care2/commonController/:id/edit(.:format) commons#edit
     common GET    /self-care2/commonController/:id(.:format)      commons#show
            PATCH  /self-care2/commonController/:id(.:format)      commons#update
            PUT    /self-care2/commonController/:id(.:format)      commons#update
            DELETE /self-care2/commonController/:id(.:format)      commons#destroy
```

Here are some actions of controller:

```
def edit
    @api = Api.find(params[:id])
end

def update
   @api = Api.find(params[:id])
   if @api.update(api_params)
      flash[:info] = request.original_url + ".do?apiname=" + "#{@api.name}"
      redirect_to root_path
   else 
      @api.statuses.new
      render :edit
   end
end

def new
  @api = Api.new
  @status = @api.statuses.new
  @status.descriptions.new
end

def create
  @api = Api.new(api_params)
  if @api.save
    flash[:info] = request.original_url + ".do?apiname=" + "#{@api.name}"
    redirect_to root_path
  else 
    @api.statuses.new
    render :new
  end
end
```

And here is my edit template:

```
<%= form_for @api, :url => commons_path, :method => :patch do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name, "API Name", class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>       
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :statuses do |status| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= status.label :name, "Status",  class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= status.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <%= status.fields_for :descriptions do |description| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= description.label :value, "Body",  class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= description.text_area :value, class: "form-control", rows: 12, cols: 65 %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

    <%= f.submit("Edit Data", class: 'btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-2') %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", root_path, class: "btn btn-danger" %>  
<% end %>
```

When I access to edit template, I can see old data and replace them with new data.
But show "No route matches [PATCH] "/self-care2/commonController" after I click submit button.

Anyone know what happen?

Comment: already post rake route result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you update specific Api, shouldn't it be like:

```
<%= form_for @api, :url => common_path(@api.id), :method => :patch do |f| %>
```